# Relationship between 3 tables in EF Core 2 and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many, ef-core-2.0

I have tables `User`, `Document` & `Status`. Need to have a relationship defined in EF Core 2.0 which can give me data like below:

```
Document               ReferredBy           AssignedTo          Status
DOC-0001(DocumentId)   USR-0001(UserId)     USR-0002(UserId)    STA-001(statusId)
DOC-0002(DocumentId)   USR-0002(UserId)     USR-0001(UserId)    STA-002(statusId)
```

Can someone help creating this? I am using SQL Server 2016.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `UserDocuments ( DocumentId, ReferredById,AssignedToId,Status)` maybe?

Comment: What are you asking for? If you already have the database set up have you already run `Scaffold-DbContext`? Or are you asking how the 3 tables can link?

Comment: I need info on how the tables shall be linked up using code first approach in EF core 2.0. How the classes will be set and how their relationship will be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get what you are after is to create those three tables in a test database as you want them then scaffold the database to your project and look at the output.

**Context**

```
public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Document> Document { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Status> Status { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"<ConnectionString>;");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Document>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.DocumentId).ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.ReferredById).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.AssignedTo)
                .WithMany(p => p.DocumentAssignedTo)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.AssignedToId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Document_User1");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.ReferredBy)
                .WithMany(p => p.DocumentReferredBy)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ReferredById)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Document_User");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Status)
                .WithMany(p => p.Document)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.StatusId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Document_Status");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Status>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.StatusName).IsRequired();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.UserName).IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

**Document**

```
public partial class Document
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public int ReferredById { get; set; }
    public int AssignedToId { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public User AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public User ReferredBy { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

**Status**

```
public partial class Status
{
    public Status()
    {
        Document = new HashSet<Document>();
    }

    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Document> Document { get; set; }
}
```

**User**

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        DocumentAssignedTo = new HashSet<Document>();
        DocumentReferredBy = new HashSet<Document>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Document> DocumentAssignedTo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> DocumentReferredBy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation in net core 2.1

This was my solution for 3 Entities. Empresa, Usuario, Perfil

**Link Entity**

```
public class EmpresaUsuarioPerfil
{
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public string PerfilId { get; set; }

    public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    public Perfil Perfil { get; set; }
    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

**Empresa**

```
public class Empresa
{
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmpresaUsuarioPerfil> EmpresaUsuarioPerfil { get; set; }

}
```

**Usuario**

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmpresaUsuarioPerfil> EmpresaUsuarioPerfil { get; set; }

}
```

**Perfil**

```
public class Perfil
{
    public string PerfilId { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmpresaUsuarioPerfil> EmpresaUsuarioPerfil { get; set; }
}
```

**DB Context**

```
public class AplicacionContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Perfil> Perfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmpresaUsuarioPerfil> EmpresaUsuarioPerfil { get; set; }

    public AplicacionContext() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmpresaUsuarioPerfil>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.EmpresaId, x.UsuarioId, x.PerfilId  });

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmpresaUsuarioPerfil>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Empresa)
            .WithMany(b => b.EmpresaUsuarioPerfil)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.EmpresaId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmpresaUsuarioPerfil>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Perfil)
            .WithMany(b => b.EmpresaUsuarioPerfil)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PerfilId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmpresaUsuarioPerfil>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Usuario)
            .WithMany(c => c.EmpresaUsuarioPerfil)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.UsuarioId);

    }
}
```